# AWS Elasticache tags

Tags: go, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm new in aws technology and redis. I want get one tag value by tag key in golang. Now I can use ListTagsForResource() func, but this func return to me all listing of tags. I want get 1 tag. How I can achieve this?

I could not find normal information either on the Internet or in the documentation.

ARN - amazon resource name,
cred - StaticCredintials with access keys

```
    svc := elasticache.New(mySession, aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1").WithCredentials(creds))
input := &elasticache.ListTagsForResourceInput{
    ResourceName: aws.String(ARN),
}

result, err := svc.ListTagsForResource(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case elasticache.ErrCodeCacheClusterNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeCacheClusterNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeCacheParameterGroupNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeCacheParameterGroupNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeCacheSecurityGroupNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeCacheSecurityGroupNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeCacheSubnetGroupNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeCacheSubnetGroupNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeInvalidReplicationGroupStateFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeInvalidReplicationGroupStateFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeReplicationGroupNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeReplicationGroupNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeReservedCacheNodeNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeReservedCacheNodeNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeSnapshotNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeSnapshotNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeUserNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeUserNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeUserGroupNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeUserGroupNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case elasticache.ErrCodeInvalidARNFault:
            fmt.Println(elasticache.ErrCodeInvalidARNFault, aerr.Error())
        default:
            fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
        }
    } else {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    return
}


fmt.Println("Get Data", result)
```

I found only this function for get data from cluster (ListTagsForResource).

Console

```
PS C:\Users\MrDipper\go\src\redisConn> go run main.go
```

Get Data {
{
Key: "Service",
Value: "ElastiCache"
},
{
Key: "APIVersion",
Value: "20150202"
},
{
Key: "APIersion",
Value: "20150202"
},
{
Key: "Sevice",
Value: "ElastiCache"
}
]
}

Comment: Can you loop through the results you get for the resource you wanted, and extract just the listings which match the tag you need?

Comment: Can you please show what have you done so far?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Are you trying to fetch the value of a single tag of an ElastiCache instance using Golang, if I get this right? Looping through the tags slice returns works for you or?